# Appcelerator Titanium: Hidden search bar slides into view when a new window is opened

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I've implemented the hidden search bar for iOS using the Titanium Alloy framework, using the `searchHidden` property on a TableView.

It works well at first, the search bar is hidden... But when the user taps on a menu item and opens a new window, it causes the search bar to appear suddenly as the new window is animating into view. And then when the user goes back to the original window with the TableView (by tapping `Back`), the search bar is there, when it should be hidden.

Here is my view:

```
<Alloy>
    <NavigationWindow id="navWin">
        <Window class="container">
            <TableView onClick="doClick" id="theTable" searchHidden="true">
                <SearchBar></SearchBar>
                <TableViewRow title="Item One"></TableViewRow>
                <TableViewRow title="Item Two"></TableViewRow>
                <TableViewRow title="Item Three"></TableViewRow>
                <TableViewRow title="Item Four"></TableViewRow>
                <TableViewRow title="Item Five"></TableViewRow>
                <TableViewRow title="Item Six"></TableViewRow>
                <TableViewRow title="Item Seven"></TableViewRow>
                <TableViewRow title="Item Eight"></TableViewRow>
                <TableViewRow title="Item Nine"></TableViewRow>
            </TableView>
        </Window>
    </NavigationWindow>
</Alloy>
```

And here is my controller:

```
function doClick() {
   var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
       title: "Window",
       backgroundColor: "#FFF"
   });
   $.navWin.openWindow(win, {animated: true}); 
};

$.navWin.open();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i also face the same Situation, one of the solutions can be setting the setSearchHidden Method to be called onFocus of the window, Something like :

```
$.mainwin.addEventListener("focus",function(){
    $.theTable.setSearchHidden(true);
});
```

considering `mainwin` is the id of Window here.

<strike>**UPDATE**</strike>

okay, i have one more solution but it will need changes in your Event Listener.

you have to add a view inside each tableViewRow and have to set bubbleParent as false for the view, and the eventlistener to open another window has to be added to the newly added View, then your Searchbar will not come into play.

Something like :

```
<TableViewRow title="Item One" bubbleParent="false" >
     <View bubbleParent="false" onClick="doClick"></View>
</TableViewRow>
```

As update 1 did not worked with more than one row so here is
**UPDATE 2**

Add the following on focus, and don't forget to hide the search on opening the window.

```
$.mainwin.addEventListener("focus",function(){
    $.theTable.setSearchHidden(true);

    setTimeout(function(){
        $.search.show();
    },1000);
```

});

Although it also gives a little jerk but the search is hidden.

Comment: This does hide the search bar again after going back to the main window. However it still pops into view when opening a new window and it then animates out of view when you go back to the main window, which looks quite jerky. Is there a way to keep the search field hidden while navigating back and forth, unless the user pulls down to see it?

Comment: Thank you Dragon, this appears to work, but the View takes up the space of the entire screen height. So when I give it a fixed height, the problem with the searchBar comes back. Perhaps the view was just masking the problem?

Comment: oh, i did not tried with setting some height. Yes it seems the view was masking the Problem.from my point of view the only solution seems to be using the first solution, along with using hide and show over the searchbar, hide it on opening new window and show it on focus. Although it gives a little jerk but the searchbar is hidden.Check the update.